# Почему картинка не сохраняется в папке static/images когда ее загружает пользователь на сайте?

Tags: python, html, django

Картинка загруженная пользователем сохраняется в базе данных, но не сохраняется в папке static/images, а когда ее меняешь через базу данных она сохраняется в папку? Почему так ?

Setting.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

Models.py:

```
account_image = models.ImageField('Аватарка пользавателя', default = 'static/images/default.webp', blank = True)
```

urls.py(В приложений):

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

profile.html:

```
<input name="file" type="file" name="file" id="input__file" class="input input__file" multiple required>
```

Views.py:

```
 if request.method == "POST":
    for i in account.objects.all():
        if i.account_login == login_for_redirect:
            redact_base = account.objects.get(account_login = i.account_login)
            redact_base.account_image = request.POST['file']
            redact_base = redact_base.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

В Models.py:
`account_image` должен выглядеть так

```
account_image = models.ImageField('Аватарка пользавателя', upload_to='images/avatar/', 
blank = True)
```

upload_to =' папка в которую будет помещена картинка после загрузки ее пользователем'